# Getting Sharepoint Online to communicate with a local server over HTTPS

Tags: sharepoint-online, ssl

I'm trying to establish an analytics server with a local server that is on the local domain but there is an issue of trust relation with Sharepoint Online. Since this is SPO it needs to be under https in order to not break security.

So, I've set up my server, tried seeing if it could receive requests from SPO which it did over HTTP but once I put on a certificate in order to keep everything under HTTPS it stopped working, looking at network logs from dev tools it tells me the following error:
"Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Is there a way to establish this relationship between SPO and a local server without contacting microsoft support?

Thanks!